# Redirect from website - Android WebView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-webview

Trying to load https://web.whatsapp.com in WebView that is part of the UserInterface, results in different outcomes: When the application hasn't opened before, meaning it was just installed, it loads web.whatsapp.com.
The next time it loads www.whatsapp.com.

I tried clearing data related to the WebView:

```
CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null);

mWebView.LoadUrl(clearStorageScript);
mWebView.ClearCache(true);
mWebView.ClearHistory();

DeleteDatabase("webview.db");
DeleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");

mWebView.LoadUrl(WhatsappWeb);
```

Also, loading about:blank before doesn't work.

After that didn't work I tried clearing the App's cache, and after that it just didn't start.

***What could be the cause of redirection and how do I prevent it?***

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mWebView.loadUrl(URl);
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this lines of codes :

```
w.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
w.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
w.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
w.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12";
w.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
w.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/%F0%9F%8C%90/en");
```